# Traverse chars in String for Analysis in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

Ok so the method `myName()` is totally wrong. I'm new to coding in C. Somehow I need to traverse the string `*theName` so that I could evaluate each char in it. And I need to do this while keeping `char *name[1] = {David $ MN % Baez}` as a songle index array. Help I'm stuck!

```
 #include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char *name[1] = {"David $ MN % Baez"} ; // should work

    myName(name) ;  
    return 0 ;
}
void myName(char *theName)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(theName); i++)
    {
        if("aeiouAEIOU".IndexOf(theName) >= 0)/////// is vowel
        {
             printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a vowel", theName[i], i);
        }


        if(theName == ' ')//////
        {
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a space", theName[i], i);
        }

        else if(theName == '$' || theName == '%')/////////////////////
        {
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a symbol", theName[i], i);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a consonant", theName[i], i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a terrible confusion and before any attempt to fix your code, you should study C better. "IndexOf" doesn't exist in C as a built-in function, perhaps in Java.. your array is declared as an array of one char pointer (and that's not what you want I believe) and the initialization isn't performed right, besides I see no declaration of the function before main and some other small issues (e.g. variable declarations in preC99)

Comment: @DavidKernin it might be some kind of C#.. anyway, David Baez , you might want to read the grammar of C carefully before posting this question

Comment: No, it is supposed to be C, I code in Java so i'm really lost, but I need to get this to work. I need an array with ONE index with my name in it, that is why I used `char *name[1]`

Comment: what's the point of an array with ONE element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `char *name[1]` is an array of `char *`, kind of like `char
   name[10][1]` but can be alloced dynamiclly. As per you description I
   think you only need one dimensional array, so only use `char *` or
   `char []` is ok.
2. `sizeof` operator used to query size of the object or type, if you
   want to get the length of a string, use `strlen` instead.
3. I don't know where `IndexOf` come from, maybe other language has
   this method, but in C, no. In your code
   `if("aeiouAEIOU".IndexOf(theName)`, I guess you want to find if the
   character is vowel. Try to use some APIs from `string.h`.
4. `for (int i=0; ...` This is C++ syntax, In C, define variable out
   `for`.
5. Use `\n` in `printf` for formatting output.

Code for you reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void myName(char *theName);
int main()
{
    char name[] = {"David $ MN % Baez"} ; // should work

    myName(name) ;
    return 0 ;
}
void myName(char *theName)
{
    char vowel[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int i=0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(theName); i++)
    {
        if(strchr(vowel, theName[i]))/////// is vowel
        {
             printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a vowel\n", theName[i], i);
        }


        if(theName == ' ')//////
        {
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a space\n", theName[i], i);
        }

        else if(theName == '$' || theName == '%')/////////////////////
        {
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a symbol\n", theName[i], i);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a consonant\n", theName[i], i);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void myName(char *name);

int main(){
    char *name[1] = {"David $ MN % Baez"};

    myName(name[0]);

    return 0;
}
void myName(char *theName){
    for(int i = 0; theName[i] ; ++i){
        if(strchr("aeiouAEIOU", theName[i])){
             printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a vowel\n", theName[i], i);
        }

        if(theName[i] == ' '){
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a space\n", theName[i], i);
        } else if(theName[i] == '$' || theName[i] == '%'){
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a symbol\n", theName[i], i);
        } else{
            printf("character [ %c ] located at position %d is a consonant\n,", theName[i], i);
        }
    }
}
```